# How to make an error checker that doesn't cause numbers to be repeatedly chosen?

Tags: python

**How would I make it so there is error checking in my program when the user types in a non-integer?**

For example, If area circle is inputted, the program will ask `What is the radius of the circle?`, then if the user inputs a string it will just crash.

Another issue is that If I put a `while True:` at the top of the list of `def` statements It causes the random choice between numbers to keep choosing the same numbers.

```
set_of_numbers1 = random.randint(1, 10)
set_of_numbers2 = random.randint(10, 20)
compliment = ["Good Job!", "Nice!", "Good one!",
              "Well done!", "Amazing!", "Great!", "Fantastic!"]
incorrect = ["Incorrect!", "False!", "Wrong!",
             "Try again!", "Keep trying!", "Almost,", "Not quite!"]

def area_circle():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    radius_circle = int(input("What is the radius of your circle?\n" + ">> "))
    print("")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("The area of your circle is", math.pi * radius_circle * radius_circle)

def test_topic():
    Topic_prompt = int(input(
        "Would you like to be tested on Area (1), Perimeter (2), Volume (3) or Probability (4)?\n" + ">> "))
    if Topic_prompt == 1:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print("What is the area of a triangle with a base length of",
              set_of_numbers1, "and a height of", set_of_numbers2)
        area_triangle_answer = float(input(">> "))
        if area_triangle_answer == (0.5 * set_of_numbers1) * set_of_numbers2:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(random.choice(compliment))
        else:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(random.choice(incorrect), "The answer was", 0.5 *
                  set_of_numbers1 * set_of_numbers2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if its a number as follows and design your logic accordingly

```
radius_circle = input("What is the radius of your circle?\n" + ">> ")
if radius_circle.isnum():
    radius_circle = int(radius_circle)
```

And to randomly choose you need to place choice making statements inside the `test_topic()` function.

Comment: So I use the ```while true``` around the ```defs``` and use this for each of them?

Comment: Don't use while loop around the defs. Those are function definitions and you never want to put them in the while loop. Define them above everything, make a while loop and call them inside. Research a bit about  definitions and calling of function. Finally look out to that `while True` loop. You don't want a `while True` unless you have a conditional `break` inside